# Is there any historical example that a market is shrinking down after competition?

Tags: economics, markets

I heard a story saying that the advertising market shrink down after Google entered. I doubt this strongly because Google is doing so well with its ads, though I never know what's the older days like. I'd still like to know whether there's any example in real life that after a serious competition the market cake went smaller rather than bigger.

Comment: This question is more related to economics than personal finance. I'm pleased to tell you that http://economics.stackexchange.com/ is now in beta. I'd suggest posting there, as I'm expecting this question to be voted closed as OT here.

Comment: Regardless of Google profitability, I doubt the ads market shrank since 1998. Can you provide references for such a claim?

Comment: Sorry and I've repost to the other site. Thanks very much for pointing out!

Comment: You are most welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand, but I do know that the print classified advertising market shrank substantially after the growth of the internet - print advertising was replaced by competition from online advertising. Google's Adwords product took a big chunk of the market, as did many other websites, eg, Monster.com, Realtor.com, LandandFarm.com, etc.

Comment: But that doesn't mean that advertising market as a whole shrunk, it just means that the advertising medium has changed. If I read the OP correctly, he claims the whole market shrank...